# Go to activity with the name of returned result?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-activity, for-loop

I want to go to an activity with the name that returned from resultPhone, for example: the current phone name is GalaxyS3, then I want it to go to GalaxyS3.class. How can I do that?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] supportedPhone = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.supported_phone);
    String[] supportedVersion = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.supported_version);
    String currentPhone = android.os.Build.MODEL;
    String currentVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

    for(String cP : supportedPhone) {
        String resultPhone = cP;
        for(String cV : supportedVersion) {
            String resultVersion = cV;
            if ((currentPhone.equalsIgnoreCase(resultPhone)) && (currentVersion.equalsIgnoreCase(resultVersion))) {
                Intent gotoPhoneDetail = new Intent(this, "resultPhone" + ".class");
                startActivity(gotoPhoneDetail);
                // how can i make this go to the activity with the name return from resultPhone?
            } else {
                setContentView(R.layout.phone_checker); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you will have to switch on conditions it wont work like this such as if resultphone.equals("s3")-- then intent for each seprate 1

Comment: what i want with this is just to check 2 things, if model name and version match the string in my array, it goes to its own Activity, like if the result is GS3 it go to GS3.class. Is there another way i can do this? i'm stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `setClassName()` of [**Intent**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) this will definitely fits your solution.

```
Intent gotoPhoneDetail = new Intent(getApplicationContext());
gotoPhoneDetail.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"."+resultPhone);
```

*Note: Class must exists and must having entry in Android Manifest file*

Comment: yes i want to go to existed class, i create class for every phone model that supported in my array list

Comment: But, how would the OP declare the Activity/Class in AndroidManifest if its a dynamic class.

Comment: `the current phone name is GalaxyS3, then I want it to go to GalaxyS3.class` assuming that OP knowing on which phone he targeting and he made the same class name for it. I had given a generic solution.

Comment: this code check for phone I support in an array if it support it goes to activity i made for each phone i support. i just want to replace the Myactivity.class with resultPhone.class

Comment: for that you have to create your own logic, I just helped you how to call Intent with custom string.

Comment: Glad it works. But one question, how did you register the activity in your manifest file?

Comment: @LazyNinja see my note, You have to make entry in Manifest file manually.

Comment: @hotveryspicy Sorry the question was not directed at you, because I saw your note. Was asking the OP, how did he manage to make an entry in the manifest file dynamically? I thought it was impossible, I am asking out of curiosity.

Comment: anyway, do you know anywhere I can know all smartphone android.os.Build.Model value?

Comment: @LazyNinja actually this code only go to Activity that have the name match the name in my array list, so I make all activity for each value in my array, so if u run this app in Galaxy S3, it compares android.os.Build.MODEL value with string in my array, if this is really GS3 phone it goes to GS3 Activity that I pre-made.

Comment: @hotveryspicy great solution. yout are really hot man.+1 for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this a no go. Remember you have to register the activities in the manifest file first. How you plan to implement that?

Comment: what i want with this is just to check 2 things, if model name and version match the string in my array, it goes to its own Activity, like if the result is GS3 it go to GS3.class. Is there another way i can do this? i'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

use `startActivity()` method to start any `activity`.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,YourNewActivity.class); // In your case GalaxyS3.class
 startActivity(intent); // Like this you can start Activity.
```

And always mention the name of new activity in `AndroidMenifest` file under `application` tag.

Comment: i know how to start activity but i want to start activity from the name of the returned result, if the result is GS3 it go to GS3.class. any other way to implement this?

Comment: You can use `Switech case` condition where use resultVersion as the case and use different activity under that respective case. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the class object from its name using the following method :

```java
Class.forName ( className );
```

where className is a string holding the class name (which is resultPhone in your case).

Try the following :

```
try {
    Class <?> myActivity = Class.forName ( resultPhone );
    Intent intent = new Intent ( this , myActivity );
    startActivity ( intent );
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // Do something else, maybe warn the user that the application does not support his/her phone ...
}
```

And let me know if it works.

Comment: Are you sure that there is an activity with the name you are searching for ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Class.forName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) :

```
if ((currentPhone.equalsIgnoreCase(resultPhone)) && (currentVersion.equalsIgnoreCase(resultVersion))) {

    Class<?> phoneClass = null;
    try {
        phoneClass = Class.forName(resultPhone);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent gotoPhoneDetail = new Intent(this, phoneClass);
    startActivity(gotoPhoneDetail);

}
```

Comment: it says the The local variable phoneClass may not have been initialized

Comment: i did that and it gives error, anyway i solve it already thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Using Class.forName(resultPhone) will give you the Class object and you may use it on the intent as already suggested by many here. But the logic you use is error prone and might not be a good one in the long run. I suggest you use a 'factory class' to get the Class object.

That way you can add more supporting phones in future and also a default class if the model is not supported. The factory class might look like this

```
  class PhoneModelClassFactory{
      public static Class getPhoneModel(String className){

         if (className.equals("GS3")) return GS3.class
         else if(className.equals("GS4")) return GS4.class
         // add more here
         else  return DefaultPhoneModel.class
      }
  }
```

And now you may call from within your method

```
       Class phoneClass = PhoneModelClassFactory.getPhoneModel(currentPhone);
       Intent i = new Intent(this, phoneClass);
       startActivity(i);
```

Comment: do u know where i can find all android.os.Build.MODEL value for all phone?

Comment: @homi3kh you may ask this as a new question. Someone else might be able to answer in that case